# Why won't this return true if the word is palindrome?

Tags: python

I want the program to return true if the word is a palindrome and false if it isn't. I also have to use a for loop to print the word backwards so i don't want that to change.
This is the function:
///

```
def isPalindrome(s):
    for i in s[::-1]:
        print(i) 
    if i == s:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(isPalindrome('hannah'))
print(isPalindrome('ben'))
```

///
And this is what it prints:
///

```
h
a
n
n
a
h
False
n
e
b
False
```

///

Comment: `print` really just prints the value, it doesn't "accumulate" it in some way. `i == s` tests for s being equal to its first character. You can just `return s == s[::-1]`.

Comment: Well, what did you see for the values of `i` and `s` when you traced them?  Where are you not understanding how you got those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time your for loop gets to the last iteration here:

```
for i in s[::-1]:
    print(i)
```

the value of `i` is the first letter of the word `s`. So when you get to compare `i` with `s`, you are not comparing the word against its reverse version, but the word against its *first letter*. For example for "hannah", you're comparing

```
"hannah" == "h"
```

and for "ben" you are comparing

```
"ben" == "b"
```

which will of course be `False` in both cases.

What you want to do is compare the word `s` with its reversed version, i.e.

```
s == s[::-1]
```